How to come up with novel words for exact concepts that result from specific fact combinations: word coining acts
Here is something I would like to be able to describe with a single word:
"You hold something in your hand (or that somethibng is perhaps in your pocket or attached to your body in done way), you are coerced to put it down, or discard it, focus on what you are doing, and forget the thread of thought associated with what that object was leading you to, or where that object is."
This, is very specific.
I want to coin a new word for it.
However, there is not an app where I can type concepts in and get a word suggestion for it (math, at, a moderate, to advanced, level, and dictionaries, do this).
However, as this sentence illustrate, I want novel coinings.
I need them, because, without these describing what I am experiencing, I will never be able to talk.
There is also the issue that no app exists where you can type stuff in and get word suggestions (these, would be, novel, invented, exactly describing words for the concept).
But there is also the issue that once you see a word your mind associates it with a concept, making it difficult to go though the list (this might make the language creator distinct and different from the language's users, by means of this specific language handicap of the creator, if present).
Is language creation a one-to-many language process (coiner and users)?
How do you implement a coining act (for the concept I described in particular, and for any concept in general)?
Thanks.

As we are here on a conlanging site, there are already some good questions and answers on coining new words.
The most important thing is, that the vocabulary fits to the overall style of your conlang, this includes aspects like phonology and phonotactics (the choice and sequence of sounds). A word can be unmotivated (in the system of your conlang), i.e., without any clues of its meaning, or motivated, e.g., by being a derivation of some other word in the conlang, or a compound word. Some conlangers go further and construct a fantasy culture around their languages (or languages around the worlds they are building), a new-coined word may reflect some of this cultural influence and be motivated by that.
(EDIT): So, in the concrete and very specific example of the question, there could be a famous story known to the educated people in that world, connected to the name of an ancient hero X who had exactly this feeeling, and there is a word that sounds like "have a feeling like hero X" in your conlang.
At the end of the day, you are the conlang designer and it is your choice of the perfectly cromulent word.
